# ImageButton in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, imagebutton

I'm pretty new to Android Studio and I'm having some issues with the ImageButton in my RecyclerViews. My RecyclerView contains an item along with the ImageButton. The item which is a TextView leads to another activity when you click on it. I want the ImageButton to do the same thing but I didn't figure out yet how to do so.

I tried this code in my MainActivity but it makes the app to crash whenever I excecute it:

```
    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_piechart);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultatsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Here is the error message:

```
    Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Here is the XML of my item view:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_piechart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_pie_chart_24" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the XML of my main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Ajouter"
            android:id="@+id/btnAjouter" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my adapter:

```
    public class QuestionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuestionAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
        public List<Question> list;
        private MyViewHolder.OnQuestionListener mOnQuestionListener;
    
        public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
            
            public TextView tvNom;
            OnQuestionListener onQuestionListener;        
    
    
            public MyViewHolder(LinearLayout v, OnQuestionListener onQuestionListener) {
                super(v);
                tvNom = v.findViewById(R.id.tvNom);
                this.onQuestionListener = onQuestionListener;           
                itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
                
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onQuestionListener.onQuestionClick(getAdapterPosition());
    
            }
    
            public interface OnQuestionListener{
                void onQuestionClick(int position);
            }
        }
    
        
        public QuestionAdapter(MyViewHolder.OnQuestionListener onQuestionListener) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            this.mOnQuestionListener = onQuestionListener;
    
        }
    
        
        @Override
        public QuestionAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                               int viewType) {
            
            LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.question_item, parent, false);
            MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v, mOnQuestionListener);
    
    
            return vh;
        }
    
        // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {       
            Question QuestionCourante = list.get(position);
            holder.tvNom.setText(QuestionCourante.nom);
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

}
```

Thank you for your helps.

Comment: It because you are trying to call Imagebutton from MainActivity, where you should be calling it from your adapter class. A fairly easy solution is to create a reference of your imagebutton inside your MyViewHolder class. Then call it from onBindViewHolder just like tvNom.

Comment: Search SO for "recyclerview click listener"

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is quite simple. you are failung to reference your imageButton in the adapter. where exactly did you place the code that is causing the exception? your adapter basically needs you to tell it which view in your adapter layout is the imageButton. here the code with the correction

```
 public class QuestionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuestionAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
        public List<Question> list;
        private MyViewHolder.OnQuestionListener mOnQuestionListener;
    
        public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
            
            public TextView tvNom;
            ImageButton imageButtom;
            OnQuestionListener onQuestionListener;        
    
    
            public MyViewHolder(LinearLayout v, OnQuestionListener onQuestionListener) {
                super(v);
                tvNom = v.findViewById(R.id.tvNom);
                this.onQuestionListener = onQuestionListener;           
                itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
                imagebutton= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_piechart);
                
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onQuestionListener.onQuestionClick(getAdapterPosition());
    
            }
    
            public interface OnQuestionListener{
                void onQuestionClick(int position);
            }
        }
    
        
        public QuestionAdapter(MyViewHolder.OnQuestionListener onQuestionListener) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            this.mOnQuestionListener = onQuestionListener;
    
        }
    
        
        @Override
        public QuestionAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                               int viewType) {
            
            LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.question_item, parent, false);
            MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v, mOnQuestionListener);
    
    
            return vh;
        }
    
        // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {       
            Question QuestionCourante = list.get(position);
            holder.tvNom.setText(QuestionCourante.nom);
            holder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultatsActivity.class);
                holder.imageButton.getContext()startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

}
```

please note how I added the view in your `viewHolder` and in the `OnBindViewHolder` method

The following code does NOT belong in MainActivity, just delete it from there:

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_piechart);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultatsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tested your code and unfortunately it still doesn't work. The issue is that the findviewbyid and the MainActivity are not recognized by the ViewHolder and onBindViewHolder. As for the code that is causing the exception, I placed it in the MainActivity.

Comment: You know you have to remove the imageButton code from main activity right? the imagebutton should only be in the adapter which is where the view is actually at home

Comment: I already removed it before testing your code but nevermind I figured a way to make the imagebutton works in the adapter. thank you still.